# How to use Valgrind on an Embedded System Project that runs GHS compiled code on MIPS?

Tags: embedded, valgrind

We have a storage controller that is used as target, it runs MIPS and has some additional hardware that goes with it. Development is done with Green Hills Compiler. Can we use VALGRIND to perform analysis on the code base ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your target is not running Linux or an OS with a POSIX API it is unlikely that you will be able to build and execute Valgrind natively.  One possibility is to build your embedded code on Linux in a suitable test harness and execute tests on that.